# How to handle a Promise call to Firestore and call agent.add()

Tags: javascript, promise, chatbot

I am trying to make a call to a Cloud Firestore Beta from DialogFlow inline editor and then call agent.add(...) and I don't understand what I need to do to make it work.  The call on its own works great and I am getting the correct values however the execution continues and the Promise even after returning does not continue to execute the agent.add() part.  Here is my code:

```
function foodcatHandler(agent){
  if (request.body.queryResult.allRequiredParamsPresent === true) {
    var foodIDsRef = firestore.collection('foodcats').doc('foodIDs');
    var category = request.body.queryResult.parameters['category-codes'];
    console.log(category);
    var catVal;
    foodIDsRef.get().then( doc => {
        console.log("Promise returned");
        catVal = doc.get(category);
        agent.add("Sounds like a plan");
        agent.add("Here are all the restaurants serving " + category + " in your area.");
        agent.add(new Card({
            title: `Foody`,
            text: `The easiest way to order is now even simpler!!`,
            buttonText: 'Order Now!',
            buttonUrl: 'https://beta.foody.com.cy/' + pcode + '?categories=' + catVal
            })
        );
    });
  }
```

}

The part that does not work is the agent.add() statements.  The console outputs some times work and others not.  Can someone help me to resolve this?

After researching a bit online I found the solution which is the following:

```
return foodIDsRef.get().then( doc => ...
```

Apparently you need to return the promise and that will allow the agent to continue the dialog.

Comment: Try adding a `.catch(err => { console.log(err); throw err; })` to the promise chain to make any error observable.

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: I was not getting any errors no

Answer (score 0):

The solution is that you need to return a Promise back.  That is at the point where the call to the DB is made just use the return keyword.